# Laravel full text search

Tags: php, database, search, laravel

I'm trying to implement a full text search query to the database. This is in the specification that my client sent me:

```
"The free text search limits the result of the data table to records with a matching first
name, last name, country, city, state, or zip code. If several words are input,
each word must match one of the columns for a record to be visible."
```

I made some *very* ugly spaghetti code in my controller to try if it works:

```
public function search($searchTerms){
        $searchTerms = explode(' ', $searchTerms);
        $results = array();
        foreach ($searchTerms as $searchTerm) {
            if (!People::where('firstname', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchTerm.'%')->get()->isEmpty()) {
                array_push($results, People::where('firstname', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchTerm.'%')->get());
            }
            else if (!People::where('lastname', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchTerm.'%')->get()->isEmpty()) {
                array_push($results, People::where('lastname', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchTerm.'%')->get());
            }
        }
        return $results;
    }
```

And this is my call to this function:

```
$data->people = $this->search(Input::get('search'));
```

The problem is that if there is no search input, I use this to get all data:

```
$data->people = People::orderBy($order)->paginate(10);
```

And by getting the search results as an array, I get the following error in my views:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$firstname (View: /home/projects/pplproject/app/views/index.blade.php)
```

How should this be implemented in the *Laravel way*?

Comment: Is "free text" supposed to be "full text"? While a small change, you would likely get search results using "full text". I'm not trying to be nitpicky.

Comment: I believe it's supposed to be full text as well. Didn't know that it's called that, thanks for the heads up! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically, the goal here should be to run this all in one query. Here goes:

```
$searchTerms = explode(' ', $searchTerms);
$query = People::query();

foreach($searchTerms as $searchTerm){
    $query->where(function($q) use ($searchTerm){
        $q->where('firstname', 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%')
        ->orWhere('lastname', 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%')
        ->orWhere('country', 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%')
        // and so on
    });
}

$results = $query->get();
```

For related models you can try something like this:

```
foreach($searchTerms as $searchTerm){
    $query->where(function($q) use ($searchTerm){
        $q->where('firstname', 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%')
        ->orWhereHas('relationName', function($relation) use ($searchTerm){
            $relation->where('relation_attribute', 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%');
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works great! I also have 2 columns in my database which have foreign keys. How is your answer modifiable to be able to search those too by name?

Comment: You're welcome. Take a look at the updated answer. Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Just another thing: is it possible to order the results with `orderBy()`? I tried to call it after the last `orWhere` and on the model (`People::orderby('firstname')->query()`), but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Do either `$query = People::orderBy('firstname');` or `$results = $query->orderBy('firstname')->get();`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$query = People::query();
    $searches = explode(' ', $request->query('q'));
    
                if (isset($searches)) {
                    foreach ($searches as $search) {
                        $query->where(function ($q) use ($search) {
                            $q->where('firstname', 'ilike', '%' . $search . '%')
                                ->orWhere('lastname', 'ilike', '%' . $search . '%');
                        });
                    }
                }
    
                $data = $query->get();
    
                return ([
                    'success'   => true,
                    'response'  => $data,
                    'message'   => 'Your message here'
                ]);
```