# FullText search in laravel 5

Tags: mysql, laravel, full-text-search

I have query regarding fulltext search in laravel.

I applied index in various columns.

I have one keyword

> bar soap

now i need record in following sequence.

- bar soap
- soap bar
- bar
- soap

My query is here

```
select `inventories`.*, MATCH (title, short_description, brand, long_description, inventory_code, product_code) AGAINST ('bar soap' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score from `inventories` where MATCH (title, short_description, brand, long_description, inventory_code, product_code) AGAINST ('bar soap' IN BOOLEAN MODE) order by `score` desc
```

I have also review this [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html).

Your help would be appreciate.

Comment: what error are you getting or you want to make it in laravel?

Comment: @DilipHirapara I'm not gettting any error but i want result in sequence which is indicate in question.

Comment: Have you tried with `IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE`

Comment: yes I tried natuaral laguage mode but it not work @DilipHirapara

Comment: Why don't you use laravel scout?

Comment: My project is developed in laravel 5.1 @SalarBahador

Answer (score 1):

**InnoDB** tables require a **FULLTEXT** index on all columns of the **MATCH()** so first give FULLTEXT index

Run this query:

```
  ALTER TABLE `inventories` ADD FULLTEXT(`title`,`short_description`,`brand`,`long_description`,`inventory_code`,`product_code`);
```

Then you are able to run full-text search:

```
SELECT * FROM inventories 
WHERE MATCH(title, short_description, brand, long_description, inventory_code, product_code)
AGAINST('bar soap' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

Comment: I inserted your all string in table and searched with fulltext and got soap bar, bar soap, bar, soap. what you get in your result? or remove a order by full text give you ordering. or one may case can be happen you are searching with all field, Search with only title and check what orders are you getting. Hope you get solution.

Comment: Got your solution?

Comment: How, Can you tell me?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
    // Text
    $search = 'bar soap';
    $parsedSearch = explode(' ', 'bar soap');

    // Create pattern
    $patterns = [];
    $patterns[] = $search; // bar soap
    $patterns[] = $parsedSearch[1] . ' ' . $parsedSearch[0]; // soap bar
    $patterns[] = $parsedSearch[0]; //bar
    $patterns[] = $parsedSearch[1]; //soap


    // Set Query
    $query = "select `inventories`.*, MATCH (title, short_description, brand, long_description, inventory_code, product_code) AGAINST ('bar soap' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score from `inventories` where MATCH (title, short_description, brand, long_description, inventory_code, product_code) AGAINST ('bar soap' IN BOOLEAN MODE) order by field(`score`," . implode(',', $patterns) . ")";

    return $query;
```

You might want to create a function to create the pattern to support other search and then use MySQL `ORDER BY FIELD` function to sort it.

Comment: @DharmeshRakholia does it show any errors when you run the query?

Comment: I'm not getting any error. I don't get result which is I indicated in question.

Comment: @DharmeshRakholia i found this : https://arianacosta.com/php/laravel/tutorial-full-text-search-laravel-5/ .

Comment: @DharmeshRakholia there is also a way using eloquent, but I think the previous link is better. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28486987/7340954